# Connections at Login Server, forwarding to World Server

Tags: c#, sockets, mmo

I have a few questions regarding sockets, I searched but couldn't find a direct answer.

I have a login server, and a world server. I connect from the `TcpClient to the TcpListener` on the `login server`. I want `both a Tcp and a Udp connection on the world server`, so once login has been checked, I redirect the `TcpClient` to the world server using `TcpClient.Connect`.

After this process, I tell the client to connect via `Udp to the login server`, and then use `Socket.Connect` to forward again to the world server.

The reason I'm forwarding and not sending client messages to the client to redirect, is that I only `want to expose the login server IP and port to the client`.

I'm not experienced with sockets, is there a better way to redirect without exposing the world server IP and port?

Comment: My theory was tested this afternoon, and failed gloriously. Seems I cannot redirect a connection on the server. I'm gonna have to have a rethink of this, the theory was there, but -1 for not testing first..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the image on this page: http://next-gen.cc/

What you are looking for is a connection server that will maintain one connection to a client socket and keep the state of the client (connected, authenticated, playing, disconnected).

Once the player logs in, the connection server opens its own socket to the right game server and forwards all messages there, also when a game server wants to send the client data it will send it to the connection server which in turn sends it to the client.
In other words, make your login/connection server function as a router between the client and your game world.